# mvcSiteMapNode hide child nodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using the nuget package MvcSiteMapProvider to create my menu structure.  I have a tab called "DTLSA" and when users hover that I only want "Application Status" and "Apply Now" visible.  So from "Personnel" and below would all be hidden in the structure.  However, if a user is on "Personnel" or any of the other pages I want the "DTLSA" to have the css class "active" applied to it (that's the only reason why I have them here).  If I set the `visibility=!*` it doesn't set the DTLSA tab as active.  Is it possible to set it active but keep those options from being displayed in the dropdown?

Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="DTLSA" url="#">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Application Status" controller="application" action="index" area="" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Apply Now" controller="application" action="applynow" preservedRouteParameters="applicationId" area="" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Personnel" controller="application" action="personnel" preservedRouteParameters="applicationId" area="" visibility="!*" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Review" controller="application" action="review" area="" preservedRouteParameters="applicationId" visibility="!*" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Checkout" controller="application" action="checkout" area="" preservedRouteParameters="applicationId" visibility="!*" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Confirmation" controller="application" action="confirmation" preservedRouteParameters="applicationId" area="" visibility="!*" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

MenuHelperModel display template:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
@foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { 
    <li class="@(node.IsCurrentNode || node.Children.Any(n => n.IsCurrentNode) ? "active" : "") @(node.Children.Any() ? "dropdown" : "")">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node) 
        @if (node.Children.Any()) {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
        }
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `node.IsInCurrentPath` property to determine if the node is part of the current path (whether it has visible children or not).

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
@foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { 
    <li class="@(node.IsInCurrentPath && !node.IsRootNode ? "active" : "") @(node.Children.Any() ? "dropdown" : "")">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node) 
        @if (node.Children.Any()) {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
        }
    </li>
}
```